# Proving $\|u\|_{L^\infty(0,T;H)}\leq C$ from a given hint.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, weak-convergence, bochner-spaces

My question concerns to the problem 6, chapter 7, of Evans PDE book (2nd edition).

In the book a hint is given but I couldn't get a solution from it. On the other hand, I got a solution without following the hint. So, I have two questions:

- How to solve the problem using the idea in the given hint?
- Is my solution (which doesn't follow the given hint) correct?

> **Problem:** Suppose $H$ is a Hilbert space and $u_k\rightharpoonup u$ in $L^2(0,T;H)$. Assume further we have the uniform bounds 
>   $$\underset{0\leq t\leq T} {\operatorname{ess\;sup}}\|u_k(t)\|\leq C\qquad (k=1,2...) $$
>   for some constant $C$. Prove 
>   $$\underset{0\leq t\leq T} {\operatorname{ess\;sup}}\|u(t)\|\leq C$$

**Given hint:** We have $\int_a^b(v, u_k(t))\; dt \leq C\|v\||b - a|$ for $0 \leq a \leq b \leq T$ and $v\in H$.

**My solution:** I will use the identification $L^\infty(0,T;H)\cong [L^1(0,T;H')]'$.

The sequence $\{u_k\}$ is bounded in $L^\infty(0,T;H)$ because 
$$\|u_k\|_{L^\infty(0,T;H)}=\underset{0\leq t\leq T} {\operatorname{ess\;sup}}\|u_k(t)\|\leq C,\qquad \forall \ k\in\mathbb{N}.$$

It follows that there are a function $v\in L^\infty(0,T;H)$  and a subsequence of $\{u_k\}$ (which will not be relabeled) such that
$$u_k \overset{*}\rightharpoonup v\quad\text{in}\quad L^\infty(0,T;H).$$
Therefore,
$$\|v\|_{L^\infty(0,T;H)}\leq\liminf_{n\to\infty}\|u_k\|_{L^\infty(0,T;H)}\leq C.$$
But
$$\left\{\begin{align}
u_k\rightharpoonup u\quad&\text{in}\quad L^2(0,T;H)\\
u_k \overset{*}\rightharpoonup v\quad&\text{in}\quad L^\infty(0,T;H)
\end{align}\right.$$
implies $u=v$ and thus
$$\underset{0\leq t\leq T} {\operatorname{ess\;sup}}\|u(t)\|=\|u\|_{L^\infty(0,T;H)}=\|v\|_{L^\infty(0,T;H)}\leq C.$$

---

### EDIT

*Here are the details on the conclusion $u=v$. I'd like to know if it's ok.*

We have
$$\begin{align}u_k\overset{*}\rightharpoonup v\quad&\text{in}\quad L^\infty(0,T;H)\cong [L^1(0,T;H')]'\tag{1}\\
u_k\rightharpoonup u\quad&\text{in}\quad L^2(0,T;H)\cong [L^2(0,T;H')]'\tag{2}
\end{align}$$

From $(2)$ we get
$$u_k\overset{*}\rightharpoonup u\quad\text{in}\quad [L^2(0,T;H')]'\tag{3}$$
because $L^2(0,T;H')$ is reflexive. Precisely, $(1)$ and $(3)$ mean
$$\left\{\begin{align}
Tu_k\overset{*}\rightharpoonup Tv\quad&\text{in}\quad [L^1(0,T;H')]'\\
Fu_k\overset{*}\rightharpoonup Fu\quad&\text{in}\quad [L^2(0,T;H')]'
\end{align}\right.$$
where $T$ is the isomorphism from $L^\infty(0,T;H)$ to $[L^1(0,T;H')]'$ and $F$ is the isomorphism from $L^2(0,T;H)$ to $[L^2(0,T;H')]'$. It follows that
$$\begin{align}
(Tu_k)(f)\to (Tv)(f)\quad&\text{in}\quad \mathbb{R},\qquad\forall\ f\in L^1(0,T;H')\tag{4}\\
(Fu_k)(h)\to (Fu)(h)\quad&\text{in}\quad \mathbb{R},\qquad\forall\ h\in L^2(0,T;H')\tag{5}
\end{align}$$

From $(4)$ we get
$$(Tu_k)(h)\to (Tv)(h)\quad\text{in}\quad \mathbb{R},\qquad\forall\ h\in L^2(0,T;H')\tag{6}$$

From the explicit form of the isomorphisms $T$ and $F$ we conclude that
$$(Tu_k)(h)=(Fu_k)(h),\qquad\forall\ k\in\mathbb{N},\quad \forall\ h\in L^2(0,T;H')$$
So, $(5)$, $(6)$ and the uniqueness of the limit imply
$$(Fu)(h)=(Tv)(h),\qquad\forall\ h\in L^2(0,T;H')\tag{7}$$
Again from the explicit form of the isomorphisms, we conclude that
$$(Fv)(h)=(Tv)(h),\qquad\forall\ h\in L^2(0,T;H')\tag{8}$$
From $(7)$ and $(8)$ we get
$$(Fu)(h)=(Fv)(h),\qquad\forall\ h\in L^2(0,T;H')$$
which implies $Fu=Fv$ which implies $u=v$.

Comment: What do you mean by $[L^1 (0,T,H')]'$? Is it the dual space $H^{-1}$ and the dual space of $L^1$ involving time?

Comment: @AaronMaroja $[L^1 (0,T,H')]'$ is the dual of $L^1 (0,T,H')$, where $H'$ is the dual of $H$.

Comment: I see. And this isomorphism for $p = \infty$ you assume the measure is semifinite, right? Something that comes from a result in Functional Analysis.

Comment: @AaronMaroja I'm using the Riesz representation theorem for Bochner-Lebesgue spaces, according to the version given in the section 23.5 of [Kuttler's book](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Modern_Analysis.html?id=rD_-YX5y1sQC&hl=pt-BR) in which the measure space is finite (for both, $p=\infty$ and $p<\infty$). (In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1355859/70305) I explicitly mentioned the content of this theorem, after $(2)$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- From the hint you get $\int_a^b (v, u(t))\,\mathrm{d}t \le C \, \|v\| \, |b - a|$ for all $a,b \in (0,T)$ and $v \in H$. By Lebesgue's differentiation theorem (use $[t \mapsto (v,u(t))] \in L^2(0,T)$), you get $(v,u(t)) \le C \, \|v\|$ for a.a. $t \in (0,T)$ and for all $v \in H$. This shows the claim.
- Your argument is correct if $H$ is separable. If $H$ is not separable, $L^1(0,T; H')$ is not separable and you can't pick a weak-* convergent subsequence (you could work with a net). (Finally, you could elaborate a little bit why you get $u = v$.)

Comment: I've tried to elaborate the conclusion $u=v$ (see my edit). Could you give me a response?

Comment: Yes, this is ok (and (very) detailed).

Comment: Without the separability, we get a subnet that converges weak-*. Do the other steps of the proof remain valid if we replace the sequence by this subnet? Do we need more adaptations? (Just a curiosity because I'm not familiar with nets.)

Comment: @Pedro: Yes, I think so.