# dual space of $L^2(0,T;H_0^1(\Omega))$

Tags: sobolev-spaces

what is the dual space of $L^2(0,T;H_0^1(\Omega))$ with the norm
$$\|f\|:= \biggl(\int_0^T \|f\|_{H_0^1(\Omega)}^2\,dt\biggr)^{1/2}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if $X$ is a Banach space such that $X'$ is separable or reflexive and $1/p+1/q=1$, the dual of $L^p(0,T;X)$ is $L^q(0,T;X')$ in the sense that there exists a bijective linear isometry $\theta:L^q(0,T;X')\longrightarrow  \Big(L^p(0,T;X)\Big)'$.

In particular, taking $X=H_0^1(\Omega)$, we conclude that the dual of $L^2(0,T;H_0^1(\Omega))$ is $L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(\Omega))$.

*Remark:* the explicit form of $f$ allows us to characterize the weak convergence in the dual (which is done in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1355859/70305) other post).

Comment: The dual of $H^1_0$ is usually rather called $H^{-1}$ if I remember well

Comment: @LL3.14 Thanks.